# Closed form of Weighted Ordinary Least Squares calculation of the trend line

Tags: weighted-data

I would like to know if there is a closed form version of this equation:

$\beta = \frac{n\sum{xy}-\sum{x}\sum{y}}{n\sum{x^2}-(\sum{x})^2}$

But for weighted data, where the weight $w_i$ is the value of the importance I want the individual $i$ in my database to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the answer:

The formula is really close to the original OLS closed formulation:

$\beta = \frac{n\sum{(wx)(wy)}-\sum{xw}\sum{wy}}{n\sum{(wx)^2}-(\sum{wx})^2}$

There is something that should be warned:
When the sample is small, the method *will* simply don't work at all, resulting in absurd estimations of the $\beta$.

Make sure your sample is big enough!